# Open source currency conversion table from currency to dollar

Tags: sql, database, currency, currency-exchange-rates

Is there any open source (free) offering historical currency conversion for the database to connect to?

My requirement is to convert 10 currencies into dollars and join the table on dates of currency and dates of sale.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Oracle you can use Oracle Transfer Pricing.

Comment: I am using Tableau

Comment: So that won't help you.Sorry!